# Debugging AngularJS views

Tags: html, angularjs, debugging

I have AngularJS application. Let's say, `index.html` has `ng-view` or `ng-include`, and inside that I have ng-if or some custom directive. When I look at Chrome F12, I don't even see the included files. If everything goes fine, I can seem some important stuff in ng-inspector (now that batarang is dead).
But what if I need to debug. Maybe I have a complex expression in ng-if, or even if I simple want to get into a complex binding (`order.orderline[2].itemname` or similar). But how can I put breakpoints in what is essentially HTML, especially if it's dynamically loaded?

Comment: Some comment about downvote and especially close recommendation would be really nice :(

Comment: Are you asking if you can `debug` angular expressions defined within your html?

Comment: no - I am asking how can I put the breakpoints in angular components of HTML (eg., ng-if directives or {{bindings}} ).Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.